# How to convert Image to ImageSource

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, rendertargetbitmap, drawingvisual

I don't know if I'm even asking the right question; so apologies in advance. I am writing some PNGs to a canvas and I also want to simultaneously copy the PNGs to a bitmap. I want the PNGs to appear in the same locations on the bitmap as they do on the canvas.

This is the code snippet:

```
WorkingBMP = new RenderTargetBitmap(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

TreeFile = "pack://application:,,,/Images/" + TreeFile;

var image = new Image
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(TreeFile))
};
image.Width = 10;
image.Height = 10;

Canvas.SetLeft(image, x );
Canvas.SetTop(image, y );

DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
drawingContext.DrawImage(image, new Rect(x, y, image.Width, image.Height));
drawingContext.Close();

WorkingBMP.Render(drawingVisual);

MainCanvas.Children.Add(image);
```

HOWEVER, it throws the error "cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' on this line:

```
drawingContext.DrawImage(image,
                  new Rect(x, y, image.Width, image.Height));
```

Will this error be solved if I can somehow convert image to to an ImageSource or am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In the code above, you _create_ a [`BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.110).aspx) object, which _is_ an `ImageSource` (standard OOP/Liskov substitution/etc.). Why don't you just use that object? Why are you trying to convert a WPF UI element to something it's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If BitmapImage drawn directly, it should work

```
var source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(TreeFile))

drawingContext.DrawImage(source,
                  new Rect(x, y, image.Width, image.Height));
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`Image` is the control on the window. `Image.Source` is the actual bitmap `Image` retrieves to render. It may not be apparent, but your code does kind of hint at this because you are setting `Source` to your `BitmapImage`.

You need to use the source property in order to get your actual `BitmapImage` you instantiated.

You may need to cast, but this should work:

```
drawingContext.DrawImage(image.Source,
                  new Rect(x, y, image.Width, image.Height));
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this!

Answer (score -1):

Here Try this

```
WorkingBMP = new RenderTargetBitmap(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

TreeFile = "pack://application:,,,/Images/" + TreeFile;

var image = new Image
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(TreeFile))
};
image.Width = 10;
image.Height = 10;

Canvas.SetLeft(image, x );
Canvas.SetTop(image, y );

DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
drawingContext.DrawImage(new BitmapImage(new Uri(TreeFile)), new Rect(x, y, image.Width, image.Height));
drawingContext.Close();

WorkingBMP.Render(drawingVisual);

MainCanvas.Children.Add(image);
```